# How to override theme for quicktabs which actually renders a view

Tags: views, theming

In D8, I want to display a view through quicktabs. For this, at first I have created a view file and call the view through QT. The view is displays well through QT. Now, I want to change the look & feel of the view. Please look into the screen of view which I've created before.[image]

Now, based on the below theme suggestions I created the file `block--quicktabs-block--gallery-tab.html.twig` to override and place it under the "templates" folder in my theme.

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * block--quicktabsgallerytab.html.twig
   * block--quicktabs-block--gallery-tab.html.twig
   * block--quicktabs-block.html.twig
   * block--quicktabs.html.twig
   x block.html.twig
-->
```

When I write something fixed like "Hello Test" in the `block--quicktabs-block--gallery-tab.html.twig`, its showing well. However, when I tried to do something dynamic coding like below, nothing appeared.

```
{% if title %}
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for key, row in rows %}
  {% if key in rows_with_tabs %}
    {{ tabs }}
    <div class="quicktabs-main" id="quicktabs-container-{{ quicktab_id }}">
  {% endif %}
  {% if key in rows_with_page_starts %}
    {% for page_key, page in rows_with_page_starts %}
      {% if key == page %}
        <div class="quicktabs-tabpage{{ page_key > 0 ? ' quicktabs-hide' : '' }}" id="quicktabs-tabpage-{{ quicktab_id }}-{{ page_key }}"> <!-- start of tbapage -->
        {% set page_number = page_key %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  {{ row.content }}
  {% if key in rows_with_page_endings %}
    {# close .quicktabs-tabpage #}
    </div> 
  {% endif %}
  {% if key == last_index %}
    {# close .quicktabs-main #}
    </div> 
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Am I overriding the correct file? Any suggestion?

PS:
after implementing the template file as said above, the suggestions looks like:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * block--quicktabsgallerytab.html.twig
   x block--quicktabs-block--gallery-tab.html.twig
   * block--quicktabs-block.html.twig
   * block--quicktabs.html.twig
   * block.html.twig
-->
```

Comment: Seems correct, is your twig template called ? did you rebuild cache ? is the `FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:` changed with x next to your template ?

Comment: Yes, I saw that anything fixed like "XYX or TEST" within the view gets printed. I re-build the cache too. I can't understand about "changed with x next to your template". I just created a file named - `block--quicktabs-block--gallery-tab.html.twig` as said above.

Comment: Than the `FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS` should have a line like this
`x block--quicktabs-block--gallery-tab.html.twig`
the x should be on the line of your template, meaning it is using this template

Comment: Im new to drupal 8. Can you send me sample code for it? Means how to write it?

Comment: I am not telling you how to write something.  I am asking you to observe in your HTML code.  In you sample `FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:` above the x is next to `block.html.twig`.  Did it change place after you included your template and cleared cache ? Its an indicator of which twig template is used.

Comment: I understood now. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

As Sunil says you are probably using view variables in your block template

Perhaps look for another template to override further down in order to find a views template to override and use your html/twig code

[image]

**Here is what I would do.**

Find the first template inside `views-view.html.twig` in my case it is `views-view-unformatted.html.twig` (red arrow above) and copy it in your theme templates folder.  Clear cache and make sure it is used and than explore the possibility of renaming it to be specific and used only for the quicktabs block.

See [here for more info on how to name your templates](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/8.2.x)

Comment: Yes, I'm using View in QT as said in my question title. Should I first template the view like `views-view--gallery--block-1.html.twig` ?

Comment: I can't know which template name you have to use without looking at the html comments of you code, find the first template inside `views-view.html.twig` as I show in my red arrow above and copy it in your theme.  Make sure it is used (after clear cache) than explore renaming it to be specific to your quicktabs.